# Составить минимальное число из введенных цифр

Tags: c

Как отсортировать числа чтобы получилось в порядке возрастания? Input: 7 4561501 Output: 1014556. Понимаю как отсортировать , но как отсортировать и чтобы первое число не было 0 не получается , уже испробовал многое.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        char a[1000];
        int dryg[1000];
        int c, n, j = 0, buf = 0, min = 0;
        int i = 0;
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        a[0] = getchar();
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            a[i] = getchar() - '0';
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            dryg[i] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                min = i;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                    if (a[j] < a[min])
                        min = j;
                buf = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min];
                a[min] = buf;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            dryg[i] += a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%d", dryg[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: какой-то странный пример  - вам числа или цифры надо отсортировать? и отсортировать надо так, чтобы первым не был 0?

Comment: Если у вас только цифры и ноль не надо учитывать, то попробуйте по другому. Заведите массив из 10 счетчиков. Вводимую цифру используйте как индекс увеличиваемого счетчика. Затем выводите цифры, начиная со счетчика для цифры 1. Печатайте цифру столько раз, сколько указано в счетчике.

Comment: Input: 7 4561501 Output: 1014556 ну мен при вводе нужно выдавать всегда чтобы получалось наименьшее число из этих цифр. Еще пример Input: 5 54320 Output: 20345

Answer (score 1):

если задача ввести `n` цифр и отсортировать по возрастанию цифры, то это можно делать так:

1. считаем какие цифры вводились сколько раз
2. при выводе сначала выводим одну цифру больше `0` и ближайшую к `0` (т.е. от `1` до `9` приоритет)
3. уменьшаем счетчик данной цифры на `1`
4. выводим последовательно все цифры от `0` до `9` заданное кол-во раз (сколько раз их ввели)

код:

```
// кол-во введённых цифр 
int digits_count[10];
memset(digits_count, 0, 10 * sizeof(int));

// ввести n цифр и подсчитать сколько раз вводили каждую отдельную цифру
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const int digit = getchar() - '0';

    if ((digit >= 0) && (digit <= 9))
        digits_count[digit] ++;
    else
        i -= 1;
}

// вывести первую минимальную цифру большую 0
for (int digit = 1; digit < 10; digit++) {
    if (digits_count[digit] > 0) {
        printf("%d", digit);
        digits_count[digit] --;
        break;
    }
}

// вывести отсортированные цифры
for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {
    for (int count = 0; count < digits_count[digit]; count++) {
        printf("%d", digit);
    }
}
```

P.S.

комментарии - это так, для понимания, вот не помню в голом C были ли такие или надо только `/* */` ставить :)

Comment: а если мне нужно допустим число в 1000символов?

Comment: а какая разница - в чем проблема? вы все равно используете массив в 10 элементов

Comment: а все, понял принцип работы.

Comment: // = это в одну строчку. Спасибо большое вам!

Comment: к сожалению, сайт не принимает другие библиотеки. Так что, можете пожалуйста помочь с именно с решение этой задачи?

Comment: хорошо, подскажите хотя бы как вывести число и в наибольшем порядке

Comment: `сайт не принимает другие библиотеки.` какие другие задачи?
`memset`? ну заполните массив `digits_count` состоящий из 10 элементов другими способами, которые придут вам в голову

Comment: Не нужен `memset`. Лучше инициализировать при объявлении: `int digits_count[10] = {0};`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, да как угодно - это я первое что в голову пришло написал, хоть поэлементно :), но ваш пример конечно наиболее оптимальный и корректный